# Solving The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, generics

I get this error:
The type arguments for method '`ConsoleApplication1.Program.takeList<T>`(`System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>`)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I believe the compiler cannot guess the return type of the chooseList method, but it has to pass it to takeList method. Is there a way to make this work, but not decouple the chooseList method into the Main function??

```
class Program
{
    static BindingList<int> listOfInts;
    static BindingList<string> listOfStrings;
    //more lists

    static void takeList<T>(BindingList<T> list)
    {
        //do something
        return;
    }

    static object chooseList() //instead of object i would put BindingList<T>
    {
        int someCondition = 0;

        //code that changes someCondition so compiler doesnt know its value

        switch (someCondition)
        {
            case 1: return listOfInts;

            //more cases for more lists

            default: return listOfStrings;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program testClass = new Program();
        var chosenList = chooseList();
        takeList(chosenList);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is an opposite situation which should work. I would like to convert it to the above:

```
class Program
{
    static BindingList<int> listOfInts;
    static BindingList<string> listOfStrings;
    //more lists

    static void takeList<T>(BindingList<T> list)
    {
        //do something
        return;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program testClass = new Program();

        int someCondition = 0;

        //code that changes someCondition so compiler doesnt know its value

        switch (someCondition)
        {
            case 1:
                takeList(listOfInts);
                break;

            //more cases for more lists

            default:
                takeList(listOfStrings);
                break;
        }

        //Instead of the switch here, i would like to write takelist(doTheSwitch(someCondition));
    }
}
```

Comment: chosenList of type object not of type BindingList

Comment: What you're doing inherently makes no sense. The return type of a method has to be known at *compile-time*, generics merely let you express higher-order type constraints. The only sensible thing `chooseList()` can return is `IEnumerable<object>` which isn't helpful.

Comment: The closest you could do is make `chooseList` return a list based on a type parameter (e.g. make it `public BindingList<T> ChooseList<T>()`), but you can't get rid of specifying what type you want at compile-time.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I added the code i was trying to transform. If there is really no way to do it like i wrote, is there any other way to shorten the switch into a method call or something?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to have `BindingList<T>` derive from a non-generic abstract type or interface `BindingList` or `IBindingList`.  You then need a `TakeList()` overload which can accept something of that non-generic type.  Note that the generic form should probably shadow some of the methods in the abstract interface so that e.g. `Add(object)` would be shadowed by `Add(T)`; other methods could be overloaded, so that both `Contains(object)` and `Contains(T)` would both be usable [the former would allow one to check whether a `List<Cat>` contains an `Animal`; even though `Animal` does not derive from `Cat`, a variable of type  `Animal` could hold a reference to an instance of `SiameseCat`, which does].